# Transforming GeoJSON to sf distorts coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, r, geojson, sf

I am working with GeoJSON data from [this source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geoiq/gc_data/master/datasets/998.geojson). I am using  the `sf`package of `R` to plot it. This is my code:

```
dmas<-st_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geoiq/gc_data/master/datasets/998.geojson") 
%>% 
  st_transform(4326)
```

The output looks like this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data =st_geometry(dmas), fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.15, alpha = 0) +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(2163)) +   
  labs(fill  = "", 
       title = "",
       caption='') + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot graph]

However, when I try to plot some coordinates over it I obtain coordinates that do not make any sense:

```
df_sf <- dgeo %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), crs=4326)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df_sf ) + 
  geom_sf(data =st_geometry(dmas), fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.15, alpha = 0) +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(2163)) +   
  labs(fill  = "", 
       title = "",
       caption='') + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Coordinates over map]

I have already ploted these coordinates against a standard US map and know that they are "correct".

Why am I obtaining this output?

I am new to `sf`.

Comment: What output are you expecting? It looks like points in USA/Alaska/Hawaii/Puerto Rico

Comment: The only thing that looks wrong here is the duplication of the axis labels because you seem to have two grid systems on one plot... I cant replicate this but I don't have your `dgeo` data set (or any info about it) but if I try with a few points it looks fine for me. What versions of everything (sf, ggplot especially) are you on?